# How to pass variable in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this anchor tag to make a call in android using cordova.

```
<a class="lft" href="tel:7767051447">Call</a>
```

Instead of number i want to give variable value.

I have number in

```
var phone_no
```

How do i pass variable instead of static number?

Comment: `href="javascript:window.location = 'tel:' + variable;"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give the anchor an id:

```
<a class="lft" href="tel:7767051447" id="phone">Call</a>
```

and then update the `href` attribute:

```
var phone_no = '12345';
document.getElementById('phone').href = 'tel:' + phone_no;
```